# Are dynamic pointers set to null

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to create a class for 'strong exception safe' 2d char array, and I have came with question if dynamically allocated pointers are set to null (case 1 in snippet below) or they are just behave like uninitialised one? I need to know that to safely delete memory in case of exception(do I have to keep track of allocated objects, or just scan all linesArg and call delete as I assume delete on null do not have any effect),
here is my code:

```
CurrentWindowBufferBase::CurrentWindowBufferBase(const size_t linesArg, const size_t rowsArg): lines(linesArg), rows(rowsArg){
    size_t allocatedRows = 0;
    try{
        1) buffer = new char*[linesArg];
        while(linesArg)
            buffer[--linesArg] = new char[rows];
    }catch(std::bad_alloc& ex){
        while(++linesArg < lines)
            delete buffer[linesArg];
        delete []buffer;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, they point to newly initialized memory

Comment: What is a dynamic pointer?

Comment: 1.) If you not initialized them, who should do it for you? 2.) Recovering from `bad_alloc` is never a good idea.

Comment: Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: Like any other dynamic allocated object, something with type `T*` allocated on the heap.

Comment: Question: If `buffer[--linesArg] = new char[rows];` will throw an exception on new, is `linesArg` decremented?

Comment: Thanks @knivil for pointing that out anybody knows the answer and explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The `new` operator allocates memory and returns the address of the memory that is allocated, so that is a non-null value.

Under normal circumstances you can safely use the `delete` operator on a pointer that has been allocated by `new`.  Additionally, if for whatever reason you set your pointer to zero, you can still safely use `delete` without having to check whether the pointer has a zero value at the time you call `delete`.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: It is important to note that C++ does not default initialize variables, so unless you set your pointer to `nullptr` explicitly before attempting to allocate it, the odds of it just happening to be `nullptr` on a failed initialization is low.  It is also a really bad idea to try to recover from a `bad_alloc` exception as that means your execution environment is in a particularly bad state and you're likely to just die horribly soon anyways.

Comment: @Donnie, thanks for You're answer so If pointer is not initialised to null then calling delete on it will probably cause undefined behaviour, so I would have to keep on track of allocated elements. Can You also put more light on why it is bad idea to recover from bad alloc?